# How to get a list of programs that uses a particular command in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle, rpg

I have a library MYLIB which consists of user defined commands and I want to find the programs which are all using the CMDs in that Library.

I'm planning to write a Utility but before that i wanted to confirm if there are any native utilities for this thing.

Comment: Are you expecting to work from compiled objects, or by scanning the source code of your programs?

Comment: @charles, if there's any way for objects it'd be great but scanning thru source code is also would do for me .

Comment: @SanthoshAppusamy I think you can use `FNDSTRPDM`. Some suggestions here https://www.rpgpgm.com/2015/12/searching-for-strings-in-source-files.html

Comment: @Nifriz, I have already created a utility using FNDSTRPDM and few other commands. Just holding this question open for anyone who might have a different approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the green screen `FNDSTRPDM` command mentioned in the comments...

I'll point out that both common IDEs used by IBM i developers, IBM's Rational Developer for i (RDi) and Microsoft's Visual Studio Code (w/[Code For IBM i extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HalcyonTechLtd.code-for-ibmi)), include the ability to search source files for a given text string.

Lastly, a source file on the IBM i is simply a multi-membered DB table with a specific format; consisting of 3 columns.

```
Field      Type       Length  Length  Position
SRCSEQ     ZONED        6  2       6         1
SRCDAT     ZONED        6  0       6         7
SRCDTA     CHAR          100     100        13
```

`SRCDTA` can be shorter or longer than the 100 chars I've shown here.  Just depends on what you've specified on `CRTSRCPF`.
They can be read like any other table on the system.

Comment: Hello @charles, Thanks for the suggestion. I initially thought about going with the SRCDTA approach, but we would need to create aliases for every source file. Execution time of this solution might take longer than using FNDSTRPDM, especially considering the high number of source files and commands I need to search. Therefore, I decided to create a utility using FNDSTRPDM